# http2 seems to slow down static downloading

Tags: nginx, http2

I change my Nginx config for my server from http1.1 to http2, and it seems that all static images become very slow to get compared to what is it in the http1.1. How to analyze the change for images, and do I have to add some extra config for this?

this is what I have with the http2 config in Nginx:

[image]
[image]

[image]

this is what I have with the http1.1 config in Nginx:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the waterfall chart for 1.1 case ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV added in the question.

Comment: I can think about 2 possibilities for troubleshooting - running `nginX` through `strace` or enabling the debug log in `nginX`. Twenty seconds delay seems like something related to DNS - but this is just a speculation. By the way, are you running both v1.1 and 2 with TLS, or just v2 ?